# Can't Destruct the value from request in Deno(Typescript)

Tags: typescript, request, deno

I want to destruct value from API request, but I can't destruct the request value. What went wrong here?

[image]

> error

[image]

Comment: i Agree,I wanted to show the error I getting in the vs code ide. that's why thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this pattern to destruct an Object:

```
const response: any = await ...
const { title, body } = response;
```

p.s. syntax in your snippet is not valid, or at least I am not familiar with it, but it is definitely not for destructuring.

Comment: Updated workaround, but previous should work as well. Getting Typerror? Need to set type of the response (if ctx.request is generic method, set its type there), otherwise can cast it. Or just use what in my answer

Comment: The syntax looks valid, the problem is just with the typing. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring

Answer (score 1):

We need to resolve value promise in the body object before destruct

**Try this:**

```
const body = await ctx.request.body();

if(body.type === 'json'){
  const {title,body} = await body.value;
}
```